# c++ compiling error involve 2 template functions of method overloading

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, compiling of each of the template functions individually results in no error, but compiling error occurs when they are put together. Could anyone tell me why, and how to fix it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


void f(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "MyFunctionI(" << a << ',' << b << ")\n";
}

template <typename CALLABLE, typename... ARGS>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<CALLABLE(ARGS&&...)>>::value, int>::type
DoFunction(CALLABLE fn, ARGS&&... args)
{
    fn(args...);
    return 0;
}
template <typename CALLABLE, typename... ARGS>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<CALLABLE(ARGS&&...)>>::value, int>::type
DoFunction(const int flag, CALLABLE fn, ARGS&&... args)
{
    fn(args...);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int nId1 = DoFunction(f, 1, 2);
    int nId2 = DoFunction(1111, f, 1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is VC2015 and error messages is:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1469): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
1>  c:\projects_svn\ssrcontrol_svn\testtemplate1\testtemplate1\testtemplate1.cpp(31): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::result_of<int (int &&)>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1469): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1469): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1469): note: '_Callable=std::ios_base::iostate'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1469): note: '_Types={int}'
```

Additional information, if I do not use method overloading, i.e. use different names for the template function, the compiler reports no error.

Comment: it [compiles](http://cpp.sh/4npm6) properly. Same on MSVS2015 update2. I suggest you swap your functions maybe that would help

Comment: swapping the functions doesn't help :-(

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using `std::result_of` on a template variadic function is valid in c++14 but not in c++11.

Citing the documentation here ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)):

> As formulated in C++11, `std::result_of` would fail to compile when `F(ArgTypes...)` is ill-formed (e.g. when `F` is not a callable type at all). C++14 changes that to a SFINAE (when `F` is not callable, `std::result_of<F(Args...)>` simply doesn't have the type member).
>
> The motivation behind `std::result_of` is to determine the result of invoking a FunctionObject, in particular if that result type is different for different sets of arguments.

So to wrap it up: the error is caused by how the template type deduction is implemented in the c++11 version of this function. It simply works as expected with c++14, so it might be the best solution if this is a valid option for you.

I can confirm that it compiles and works with both recent versions of gcc and clang, given the `-std=c++14` flag (but it failed with `-std=c++11`).

---

**EDIT**: OP already uses C++14

The code actually uses `std::result_of_t` which only appeared with C++14, so my remark above doesn't apply.

Also, the code would also actually work in C++11 using `typename std::result_of<CALLABLE(ARGS&&...)>::type` instead of `std::result_of_t<CALLABLE(ARGS&&...)>` (tested with clang).

So I'm not sure what's wrong. Maybe a bug in MSVC's implementation of the STL?

Comment: Well, the 'f' function I passed to both template functions is a callable type, and should be compiled without error. And I mentioned in my question, both template functions could be compiled without error if they exist individually, but has error when they are placed together in my code above.

Comment: You're absolutely right: it's weird. I totally missed the fact that you are using `std::result_of_t` (and not `std::result_of`) which means that you're already using c++14. Then I'm not sure why you're compiler chokes on this template specialization. It works with other compilers (clang and gcc - I don't have access to a recent MSVC).